# Файл с расширением .pile

Tags: взлом, hex, файлы

Нашел в одной игре файлик _data.pile. Достаточно большой - 650 метров. В hex редакторе в начале написано Pilex, дальше бинарная информация, осмысленной текстовой я не нашел. Утилитка file, портированная под винду, ничего не знает о таком типе файла.

Подскажите чем его открыть и что это?

Comment: я думаю, по таким данным Вам поможет только тот, кто уже ломал формат файла для этой неведомой игры. Все остальные просто пожимают плечами.

Answer (score 1):

Стырено с http://aluigi.altervista.org/papers/bms/pile.bms

```
# Prime World
# script for QuickBMS http://quickbms.aluigi.org

idstring "Pile"
goto -0x18
idstring "Pile"
get DUMMY short
get DUMMY short
get FILES long
get NAMES_OFF long
get NAMES_SIZE long
log MEMORY_FILE NAMES_OFF NAMES_SIZE
get OFFSET long
goto OFFSET
for i = 0 < FILES
    get ZSIZE long
    get SIZE long
    get OFFSET long
    get ZIP long
    get NAME_OFF long
    get CRC long
    goto NAME_OFF MEMORY_FILE
    get NAME string MEMORY_FILE
    if ZIP == 0
        log NAME OFFSET SIZE
    else
        clog NAME OFFSET ZSIZE SIZE
    endif
next i
```

Comment: Достаточно интересная штука, похоже скрипт когда то работал, теперь выдает ошибку: Error: [myfseek] the offset 0x7c29d683 in the file -1 can't be reached

Comment: Ну тогда только если `WinHex'ом` открывать `.pile` и угадывать новые оффсеты запакованных в нем файлов. Можете поискать по `zip` сигнатурам.